# How to run minify files in JavaScript project

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, minify, build-script

I minified my JS file using grunt task runner.

I have a minified file with me but i dont know how to run my project using this minified JS file.

I first 'concat' and then 'uglify'. Now, i don't know how to run.

I am using require and backbone in my Javascript project.

Code:  index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Minify POC </title>
</head>
<body>
<script src='main'>
</script>  

</body>
</html>
```

Minified JS file :

```
/*! Example 10-06-2014 */
var a=10,b=20,c=a+b;console.log("Addition of c ::"+c);
```

Original file

```
var a = 10;
var b = 20;
var c = a+ b;
console.log("Addition of c ::"+c);
```

Comment: Maybe you might wanna show some code or commands that demonstrate how you're trying to run them, that way we can help you easier?  Guessing sucks, both for you as well as all the answerers. :D  Hope this helps!

Comment: u run the same, the essential content didnt change

Comment: For instance, how do you run them when they're *not* minified?

Comment: ya essential content is not change. But, in my src folder i replaced original file with one minified file. And i am getting below error :Uncaught Error: Script error for: main

Comment: Do I need to update to every HTML pages. As my contains so my HTML pages.

Answer (score 0):

You need an HTML file to point to the new script. Uglify to a different directory and put a copy of your HTML there, but swap out the script tags...

Answer (score 0):

A usual RequireJS entry point looks like this:

```
<script data-main="main" src="lib/require.js"></script>
```

Depending on how your HTML is served, you can add require config to point at the built version. For instance if your HTML is served dynamically, you can add a `script` block that's included in the page based on environment config:

```
<script>
    var require = {paths: {main: "path/to/built/main.js"}};
</script>
<script data-main="main" src="lib/require.js"></script>
```

Now, any reference to `main` will load the built JS, rather than the unbuilt one.